# Pegar commits com palavras chaves

Tags: git, grep

Estou tentando minerar alguns dados do Git, preciso saber em quantos commits o arquivo X está presente e se nesses commits possuo alguma palavra chave de uma lista. Estou usando o seguinte comando:

```
git log --all --grep fix --follow Freak.php
```

Atualmente ele busca apenas pela palavra chave `fix`, preciso fazer com que seja possível pesquisar por mais de uma palavra chave no comando, por exemplo, por `fix` OU `error`. Como posso fazer isso?

PS¹: já vi sobre o comando `git grep`, ele não me ajuda, pois retorna um resultado bem bagunçado, preciso de algo mais limpo para capturar com o Symfony Process.

PS²: como estou usando o Symfony Process, eu já tentei colocar um `foreach` para executar o comando X vezes trocando a palavra chave em cada vez que executo, porém o processo fica lento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a documentação do `git --grep` a um comando `--or`

Documentação:
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep

O uso seria assim:

```
git log --all --grep 'fix' --or 'SEGUNDASTRING' --follow Freak.php
```

Conforme citado no blog: http://travisjeffery.com/b/2012/02/search-a-git-repo-like-a-ninja/

Este blog contem diversas outras formas de filtro.

Mas pelo seu problema você precisa manter o comando log, então a sua solução seria:

```
git log --all --grep='fix' --grep='commit' --follow Freak.php
```

Comment: Não funciona assim. A documentação é do comando `git grep`, no caso uso o `git log`. Tentei aqui e tive o erro: *fatal: ambiguous argument 'SEGUNDASTRING': unknown revision or path not in the working tree*.

Comment: Tenta algo assim
git log --grep='fix' --or --grep='SEGUNDASTRING' tenta com e sem '' @LeonardoVilarinho

Comment: Consegui assim: `git log --all --grep='fix' --grep='commit' --follow Freak.php`.

Comment: Chegando em um PC eu edito a minha resposta